# Angular 7 PrimeNg Calendar dates disappear on hover in Firefox

Tags: angular, flexbox, primeng

I am implementing the PrimeNg Calendar. When I put it on the page, without any of our styles and special formatting, it works fine. When I put it on the page with all of these other options we need, the calendar dates and such, disappear then reappear.

I've tried for HOURS stripping it down to the basics, but cannot figure out what is causing the issue. I have experimented with removing the width styles from the elements and the calendar appears fine, but we need these.

I created a stackblitz for this issue, replicating it. This is only an issue in firefox, not in Chrome. I know the CSS isn't completely applied, and it's a very messy look, but it replicates the issue.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-b51scg

I am expecting this to not have these dates, and other elements of the calendar, disappear. There must be something in this that Firefox is having issues with.

Comment: things to add: Version of firebox you are trying it

Comment: "I put it on the page with all of these other options we need" what are those options FYI I saw you imported jquery... that's a big no no in the angular world. You shouldn't be using jQuery in Angular. It's bad practice

Answer (score 0):

The **css** you added is breaking the calendar(when you hover on a date)

```
span {
    &.ui-calendar {
        display: inline; //this line is breaking your code
        button {
          ....
        }
    }
}
```

Also the very top part of the calendar when you select a month is breaking:

```
.placed-input {
    ...
    width: 80%; //this line is breaking your code
}
```

I don't know what exactly you are trying to accomplish

Based on the primeng page nad your calendar with extra styling works fine:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date3" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
```